# Add image support to GD on Debian

Tags: apt, debian-squeeze, gd, php5-gd

I've recently replaced our aging (386) monitoring machine with something a bit more recent and because I had driver issues with CentOS I decided to use Debian 6 (Squeeze) instead. While in the past I've preferred to compile from source this time I thought I'd try to stick with apt and install packages that way.

I suppose it was inevitable that there are issues. Of main concern is that there appears to be no image support in GD with error messages such as this whenever I try to create an image in code (PHP or Perl):

```
 Can't locate object method "png" via package "GD::Image"
```

I can replace "png" with "jpg" or "gif", all result in the same error.

I can't locate any packages which look like they might add the needed graphic support. How can I resolve this without creating a dependency hell for myself?

**EDIT**

Based on the various comments below I've come to the conclusion that something is screwed with at least part of my GD installation, so the question now becomes: How can I uninstall the various parts and reinstall them without causing myself any more problems than I already have? Sadly, I'm not in a position to wipe this machine and start over.

Now I remember why I've previously stayed away from these package managers and the dependency nightmares they create. :(

Comment: A quick [`apt-get install libgd-gd2-perl`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/perl/libgd-gd2-perl) on my Squeeze box allowed me to use [this example source](http://www.emunix.emich.edu/~evett/BioinformaticsTools/Mastering%20Perl/gd.pl) to create a .PNG with Perl.  Not sure about PHP.

Comment: The default php5-gd library seems to create png image files for me without any problems.  Are you sure that php5-dg got loaded properly?  Are you sure there isn't some kind of bug in the script/program trying to use it?

Comment: @jscott, I have `libgd-gd2-perl` installed and rechecked with your sample code (very similar to what I was already trying) and still get the same error.

Comment: @Zoredache, I even tried uninstalling `php5-gd`, rebooting (just to be sure) and reinstalling it (and restarting Apache). Testing this time with jscott's sample code. Still no go.

Comment: FWIW I don't have `php5-gd` installed.  Without `libgd-gd2-perl`, I get `Can't locate GD.pm in @INC` trying to use the sample.

Comment: I use gd with php on squeeze without problems at all. installed `libgd2-xpm` and `php5-gd` ... works like a charm :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the libpng12-0 package is really installed ?

Comment: @Dom, when I try to install libpng12-0 I get "libpng12-0 is already the newest version".

Comment: Do you see something in general logs ? Is there SELinux active ? Really strange, it works really well on our 10 servers without problem !

Comment: @Dom, nothing in the general logs and SELinux is not even installed, not that it should have the effect being observed.

Answer (score 1):

Perl looks for modules in the directories of the `@INC` array, just like Bash does with `$PATH` for commands. The GD installed by apt is probably being overridden by something else in the `@INC`.

Look for files named `GD.pm` in your system, it should show only the Debian one in `/usr/lib/perl5/GD.pm`.

You can check your `@INC` using `perl -e 'print join "\n", @INC'`, mine is

```
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.10
/usr/share/perl/5.10
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

Comment: GD.pm is within the @INC path but this wouldn't have an effect on PHP and the question quite clearly states "whenever I try to create an image in code (PHP or Perl)".